# Python: Get specific text in a line of a file using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to search through a text log file line by line and I want to save a certain part of a line as a variable. I am using Regex but don't think I am using it correctly as I am always get `None` for my variable `string_I_want`. I was looking at other Regex questions on here and saw people adding `.group()` to the end of their `re.search` but that gives me an error. I am not the most familiar with Regex but can't figure out where am I going wrong?

Sample log file:

```
2016-03-08 11:23:25  test_data:0317: m=string_I_want max_count: 17655, avg_size: 320, avg_rate: 165
```

My script:

```
def get_data(log_file):

    #Read file line by line
    with open(log_file) as f:
        f = f.readlines()

        for line in f:
            date = line[0:10]
            time = line[11:19]

            string_I_want=re.search(r'/m=\w*/g',line)

            print date, time, string_I_want
```

Comment: regex is wrong..you are using Javascript format of regex

Comment: Don't just guess what those `re` functions and methods do --- read the "[Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)" for a thorough introduction to using regular expressions in Python 2, and refer to the [`re` reference docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) when you need to look up specifics.  It will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `/.../` delimiters with the global flag, and use a capturing group:

```
mObj = re.search(r'm=(\w+)',line)
if mObj:
    string_I_want = mObj.group(1)
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM0fV0/2) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/veclZE):

```
import re
p = r'm=(\w+)'              # Init the regex with a raw string literal (so, no need to use \\w, just \w is enough)
s = "2016-03-08 11:23:25  test_data:0317: m=string_I_want max_count: 17655, avg_size: 320, avg_rate: 165"
mObj = re.search(p, s)      # Execute a regex-based search
if mObj:                    # Check if we got a match
    print(mObj.group(1))    # DEMO: Print the Group 1 value
```

**Pattern details**:

- `m=` - matches `m=` literal character sequence (add a space before or `\b` if a whole word must be matched)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters. We can reference this value with the `.group(1)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
(?<=\sm=)\S+
```

**Example:**

```
In [135]: s = '2016-03-08 11:23:25  test_data:0317: m=string_I_want max_count: 17655, avg_size: 320, avg_rate: 165'

In [136]: re.search(r'(?<=\sm=)\S+', s).group()
Out[136]: 'string_I_want'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
import re
def get_data(logfile):
    f = open(logfile,"r")
    for line in f.readlines():
        s_i_w = re.search( r'(?<=\sm=)\S+', line).group()
        if s_i_w:
            print s_i_w
    f.close()
```